# git clone to get files which was added/modied after specific tag

Tags: git, powershell, shell, github, gitlab

I have a requirement in db package creation. our db changes are in git .we are tagging git repo with  version.
e.g.
branch = development
file1  - no tag ,
file2  - no tag ,
file3  tagged v1.2 ,
file4  tagged v1.1 ,

I wanted to clone only files which is not yet tagged . i.e. file1 and file2 .
file3 and  file4 should not clone to my local folder. pls help
I need to create db package which is not in the production.upto v1.2 file already updated in production.i cannot send it again. so wanted to get only files which was changed after v1.2

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand how git works. (Ignoring for the moment "sparse checkouts"...) git can only clone all the files in the repo, or in the case of shallow clones, all the files at the ref being cloned.

Comment: is there any way to clone all the files. then list only updated file after tagv1.2 . then using shell script these two files can be retrieve. rest files can be deleted? someone help me in shell script

Comment: You can list all commits after a tag `git log "tagv1.2"..`. You can then play with format options to get what you want. Like `git log  --format="" --name-only "tagv1.2"..` . If necessary, pipe that to `sort -u`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your response.

1. I am first getting all the revision using
   getrevision="git log -3 --pretty=format:"%h" tag_v.1...HEAD"
2. then looping on getrevision
3. then getting all the files name which is not yet tagged
   files=$(git log tag_v.1..HEAD --pretty="format:"  --name-only $rev )
4. then apply loop to validate all the existing files
5. deleting all the files which is not in the $files
   it does not matter weather updated or modified . if it is existing after tag_v.1 then including file.

This will solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Git is not about *files*.  Git is about *commits*.  Each commit is a full archive of every file.

The `git clone` command creates a new, empty repository, then runs `git fetch` to fill it in with commits.  You'll need to get the commits in question, then do some of your *own processing on those commits*.  That is, you'll get the commit whose hash ID is given by the tag, and look at *all* the files in that commit.  Then you'll look at *all* the files in some later commit, and see which files are the same and which ones are different.

You will need to define what you mean by "added/modified since some revision", because it's possible to make commit #17 with six files: `f1` `f2` `f3` `f4` `f5` and `f6`, then make commit #18 with just five files by removing `f3`, then make commit #19 with six files by putting `f3` back, unchanged from the way it appeared in #17.  Then commit #20 might change `f4` but commit #21 changes it back.  Are files `f3` and `f4` added or modified, or are they the same?

Once you've defined what *you* mean by this, you will know—or at least be able to learn—how to find out which files meet your criteria.